# Is new-pssession the same as psexec?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is `pssession` the same as `psexec`?

If I use `new-pssession` to create a session to a remote PC, is it the same as using `psexec`?

If we can use `invoke-command -computername` to create a temporary session, what is the benefit using `pssseion` to create a persistent connection?

Under what circumstances should I use `new-pssession`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New-PSSession is used when you have multiple commands, or even a script, to be run against a remote machine. Invoke-Command and psexec both allow you to run a single command remotely, and though that command could execute a script, it's not necessarily the best tool for the job.

Comment: hum...psexec is a connection to remote pc's cmd, I can run commands as many as I want, not just a single command...

Comment: I would like to add that Invoke-Command connects, and then disconnects, so if you are going to run several commands on a remote machine you will have a lot less overhead of connecting and disconnecting if you use New-PSSession. Also a persistent session on a remote machine gives you access to modules installed on that machine that you may not have locally.

Comment: PSExec is not simply a connection to a remote pc's cmd. It runs a command, like he said. If you run CMD, then that's the command that you are running, and you can use it to do other things. PSExec has a lot more capabilities then just used as a remote command prompt shell.

Comment: PSExec requires you to use an account that's a local admin on the target machine, sends data in clear text, and uses RPC.  PS Remoting doesn't require a local admin account, and can be configured to communicate over HTTPS, so it's encrypted on the wire, resilient to network latency, and works on a fixed port that can be firewalled.