# Run batch file in specific user session (no PSExec allowed)

Tags: session, powershell, batch-file, psexec

I've one user logged in a VM, with 3 sessions opened (sessions 2, 3 and 4). I need to run a batch file in specific session, e.g.: 'C:\test.bat' in session 2.

I'm already doing this with PSExec, but I want to know if there someway to make this works **without PSExec**.

My actual code:

```
$session = $args[0]
$user = "user01"
$pass = "change123"

C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe -i $session -d \\$env:COMPUTERNAME -u $user -p $pass C:\test.bat
```

I've been thinking... If I'm the session 2, there's some way to change to session 3 (with tscon) and then run a command in the session 3?

Comment: Have you considered running `Invoke-Command` or `New-PsSession`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790493/is-that-new-pssession-the-same-as-psexec

Comment: I'll try this, but the Session of PowerShell is like a User Session? I need to New-PsSession in each user session?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Yes it is possible. But...

**Long answer:** As an example only, I have found some code in C# on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/msCJ0KJT) that does something similar. It will enumerate all sessions, find the one that is logged in to the console and execute command in the session’s context. After wrapping the code in PowerShell, adding some using statements and changing few classes and types to public, it now works. It imports all the functions you would need to accomplish your task from system DLLs.

```
$C =  @"
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Security;

    public class ApplicationLauncher
    {
        public enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
        {
            TokenUser = 1,
            TokenGroups,
            TokenPrivileges,
            TokenOwner,
            TokenPrimaryGroup,
            TokenDefaultDacl,
            TokenSource,
            TokenType,
            TokenImpersonationLevel,
            TokenStatistics,
            TokenRestrictedSids,
            TokenSessionId,
            TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
            TokenSessionReference,
            TokenSandBoxInert,
            TokenAuditPolicy,
            TokenOrigin,
            MaxTokenInfoClass // MaxTokenInfoClass should always be the last enum
        }

        public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;

        public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;

        public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
        public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL;
        public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = READ_CONTROL;

        public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000;

        public const int SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF;

        public const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        public const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
        public const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;

        public const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
                                               TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
                                               TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
                                               TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
                                               TOKEN_QUERY |
                                               TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
                                               TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                               TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                               TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT);

        public const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

        public const int TOKEN_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY;

        public const int TOKEN_WRITE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                       TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                       TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                       TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT;

        public const int TOKEN_EXECUTE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE;

        public const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

        public const int CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200;
        public const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;

        public const int IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
        public const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        public const int HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
        public const int REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

        public const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        public const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
        public const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
        public const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";

        public const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x0002;

        public const int ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

        private const uint TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;

        public static int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr lpSystemName, string lpname,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
            int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
            int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, bool DisableAllPrivileges,
            ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, int BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass,
            ref uint TokenInformation, uint TokenInformationLength);

        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

        public static bool CreateProcessInConsoleSession(String CommandLine, bool bElevate)
        {

            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

            bool bResult = false;
            uint dwSessionId, winlogonPid = 0;
            IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero, hUserTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero, hPToken = IntPtr.Zero, hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

            Debug.Print("CreateProcessInConsoleSession");
            // Log the client on to the local computer.
            dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

            // Find the winlogon process
            var procEntry = new PROCESSENTRY32();

            uint hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
            if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                return false;
            }

            procEntry.dwSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(procEntry); //sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

            if (Process32First(hSnap, ref procEntry) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            String strCmp = "explorer.exe";
            do
            {
                if (strCmp.IndexOf(procEntry.szExeFile) == 0)
                {
                    // We found a winlogon process...make sure it's running in the console session
                    uint winlogonSessId = 0;
                    if (ProcessIdToSessionId(procEntry.th32ProcessID, ref winlogonSessId) &&
                        winlogonSessId == dwSessionId)
                    {
                        winlogonPid = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (Process32Next(hSnap, ref procEntry) != 0);

            //Get the user token used by DuplicateTokenEx
            WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, ref hUserToken);

            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
            var tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
            var luid = new LUID();
            hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, false, winlogonPid);

            if (
                !OpenProcessToken(hProcess,
                    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY
                    | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID | TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_WRITE, ref hPToken))
            {
                Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession OpenProcessToken error: {0}",
                    Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }

            if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr.Zero, SE_DEBUG_NAME, ref luid))
            {
                Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession LookupPrivilegeValue error: {0}",
                    Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }

            var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa,
                    (int) SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int) TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                    ref hUserTokenDup))
            {
                Debug.Print(
                    String.Format(
                        "CreateProcessInConsoleSession DuplicateTokenEx error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                CloseHandle(hPToken);
                return false;
            }

            if (bElevate)
            {
                //tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
                //tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

                tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
                tp.Privileges = new int[3];
                tp.Privileges[2] = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                tp.Privileges[1] = luid.HighPart;
                tp.Privileges[0] = luid.LowPart;

                //Adjust Token privilege
                if (
                    !SetTokenInformation(hUserTokenDup, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenSessionId, ref dwSessionId,
                        (uint) IntPtr.Size))
                {
                    Debug.Print(
                        String.Format(
                            "CreateProcessInConsoleSession SetTokenInformation error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                            Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                    //CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    //CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                    //CloseHandle(hPToken);
                    //CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
                    //return false;
                }
                if (
                    !AdjustTokenPrivileges(hUserTokenDup, false, ref tp, Marshal.SizeOf(tp), /*(PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)*/
                        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    int nErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                    if (nErr == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
                    {
                        Debug.Print(
                            String.Format(
                                "CreateProcessInConsoleSession AdjustTokenPrivileges error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                                nErr));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession AdjustTokenPrivileges error: {0}", nErr));
                    }
                }
            }

            uint dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
            IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
            if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserTokenDup, true))
            {
                dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
            }
            else
            {
                pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            // Launch the process in the client's logon session.
            bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup, // client's access token
                null, // file to execute
                CommandLine, // command line
                ref sa, // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                ref sa, // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                false, // handles are not inheritable
                (int) dwCreationFlags, // creation flags
                pEnv, // pointer to new environment block 
                null, // name of current directory 
                ref si, // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                out pi // receives information about new process
                );
            // End impersonation of client.

            //GetLastError should be 0
            int iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            //Close handles task
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            CloseHandle(hUserToken);
            CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
            CloseHandle(hPToken);

            return (iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser == 0) ? true : false;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern int Process32First(uint hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern int Process32Next(uint hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(uint dwFlags, uint th32ProcessID);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hSnapshot);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        private static extern uint WTSQueryUserToken(uint SessionId, ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, ref uint pSessionId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, // handle to process
            int DesiredAccess, // desired access to process
            ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

        #region Nested type: LUID

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public int LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

        #endregion

        //end struct

        #region Nested type: LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
        {
            public LUID Luid;
            public int Attributes;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: PROCESSENTRY32

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESSENTRY32
        {
            public uint dwSize;
            public readonly uint cntUsage;
            public readonly uint th32ProcessID;
            public readonly IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            public readonly uint th32ModuleID;
            public readonly uint cntThreads;
            public readonly uint th32ParentProcessID;
            public readonly int pcPriClassBase;
            public readonly uint dwFlags;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public readonly string szExeFile;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: PROCESS_INFORMATION

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int Length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL

        private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3,
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: STARTUPINFO

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public String lpReserved;
            public String lpDesktop;
            public String lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            internal int PrivilegeCount;
            //LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            internal int[] Privileges;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: TOKEN_TYPE

        private enum TOKEN_TYPE
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation = 2
        }

        #endregion

        // handle to open access token
    }
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $C -ReferencedAssemblies mscorlib

[ApplicationLauncher]::CreateProcessInConsoleSession("cmd.exe",$false)
```

So one way to accomplish what you are after would be to rewrite C# code to find the specific session you need. Second way would be to import DLLs and functions directly in PowerShell, using Add-Type and rewrite the logic in PowerShell. Neither is easy. Either way, I suspect this is “Too Hard” as you already have a way to do this with **PSExec**.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to use the pure PowerShell if theres a simple way to do the same thing of PSExec. Thanks for that!

Comment: Maybe if you expand your question a little bit and provide an example of PSExec command line/script that you have at the moment. As it is, it looks like you are trying to impersonate a user in an already logged on session. There is no easy PowerShell way to do this.

Comment: @Lucas, thanks for that. Just as I thought. What “PSExec –i” does is User Impersonation. I'm not a .NET programmer, but from what I have seen discussed here and elsewhere, there is no way to do this natively in .NET. All solutions resort to using unmanaged code (similar to code in my answer.). As PowerShell is a consumer of .NET, this means that there is no easy native way to do this in PowerShell. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

### **Try the following.**

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public STARTF dwFlags;
    public ShowWindow wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[Flags]
public enum CreationFlags : int
{
    NONE = 0,
    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
    DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
    CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00000800,
    CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
    CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
    EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000,
    CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
    CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
}

[Flags]
public enum STARTF : uint
{
    STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001,
    STARTF_USESIZE = 0x00000002,
    STARTF_USEPOSITION = 0x00000004,
    STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS = 0x00000008,
    STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010,
    STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN = 0x00000020,  // ignored for non-x86 platforms
    STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040,
    STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080,
    STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100,
}

public enum ShowWindow : short
{
    SW_HIDE = 0,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
    SW_NORMAL = 1,
    SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
    SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
    SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
    SW_SHOW = 5,
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
    SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
    SW_SHOWNA = 8,
    SW_RESTORE = 9,
    SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
    SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11,
    SW_MAX = 11
}

public static class wtsapi32
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(Int32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);
}

public static class advapi32
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName, 
    string lpCommandLine, 
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, 
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles, 
    CreationFlags creationFlags, 
    IntPtr lpEnvironment, 
    string lpCurrentDirectory, 
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, 
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
}
"@


$sessionID = 2
$token = [IntPtr]::Zero

$ret = [wtsapi32]::WTSQueryUserToken($sessionID, [ref] $token)

$si = New-Object STARTUPINFO
$pi = New-Object PROCESS_INFORMATION

$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($si)
$si.wShowWindow = [ShowWindow]::SW_SHOW

$pSec = New-Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$tSec = New-Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$pSec.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($pSec)
$tSec.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($tSec)

$dwCreationFlags = [CreationFlags]::NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS -bor [CreationFlags]::CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

[advapi32]::CreateProcessAsUser($token, "c:\windows\notepad.exe", $null, [ref] $pSec, [ref] $tSec, $false, $dwCreationFlags, [IntPtr]::Zero, "c:", [ref] $si, [ref] $pi)
```

Comment: This will run the program in the specific session with the credential of the user logged onto that session. If you want to run with your account/System, code needs to be changed.